# PHP User Level / Admin panel

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working for a code that differentiated between Members and Admins but when I login he just know me as an Admin. I appreciated every help I can get!

```
$pdoStatement = $conn->prepare( 'SELECT email FROM tbl_user WHERE user_level = 1' ); 
$pdoStatement->execute(); 
$resultObject = $pdoStatement->fetchAll(); 

if ($resultObject[0] && $_SESSION['loged_in']) {    
  $_SESSION['is_admin'] = true;
  header('Location: index.php?page=admin.php');      
} else{
  $_SESSION['is_admin'] = false;
  $_SESSION['is_member'] = true;
  header('Location: index.php?page=member.php');
}
```

Here is my table structure for tbl_user:

```
id int(11)  Primarykey
state varchar(255)
f_name varchar(255)
l_name varchar(255)
email varchar(255)
conf_email varchar(255)
password varchar(255)
conf_password varchar(255)
answer varchar(255)
user_level int(11)
```

below that is my table structure for tbl_user_level

```
id int(11)
name varchar(255)
```

id 1 (name) stands for Admin and 2 for Member

EDIT: The code works fine now with the result in the comments. I'm sorry for my mistakes I'm new here. I'm improving for the maybe next questions. I wish ya a good day!

Comment: plz also provide your table structure for a better solution

Comment: Do you store the user's ID in the session array for logged in users? At the moment the query only looks to see if there's any users of level 1, it doesn't check for what level the logged in user is

Comment: The session 'loged_in 'has just the value 'true' which will be activated when the user entered his password successful.

Comment: can you please provide result of var_dump($resultObject) ? This will show structured data of results and show if the query actually found any records.

Comment: I tested it. There is no output by: echo $resultobject if you did mean that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$pdoStatement = $conn->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_level = 1' ); 
$pdoStatement->execute(); 
$resultObject = $pdoStatement->fetchAll(); 

foreach ($resultObject as $data) {
 if ($data['email'] == $_POST['email']) {    
  header('Location: index.php?page=admin.php');      
} else{
  header('Location: index.php?page=member.php');
}
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but that didn't work too :/

Comment: It actually worked!! Thank you verry much Krishna Gupta!

Comment: This piece of code makes no sense. 1. Searching for a record must not be done with a loop. 2. If the query returns more than one result, `header()` gets called multiple times. 3. The overall algorithm makes no sense ("redirect to admin page if the current user is the first admin in the database")

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdoStatement = $conn->prepare(
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_user WHERE user_level = 1 AND email = ?'
); 
$pdoStatement->execute(array($_POST['email'])); 
$resultObject = $pdoStatement->fetchAll();

if($resultObject[0] == 1) { // COUNT(*) == 1 <=> admin user found
    header('Location: index.php?page=admin.php');
} else {
    header('Location: index.php?page=member.php');
}
```

Alternatively:

```
$pdoStatement = $conn->prepare(
    'SELECT user_level FROM tbl_user WHERE email = ?'
); 
$pdoStatement->execute(array($_POST['email'])); 
$resultObject = $pdoStatement->fetchAll();

if(count($resultObject) === 0) {
    throw new Exception('User not found');
}

if($resultObject[0] == 1) { // user_level == 1
    header('Location: index.php?page=admin.php');
} else {
    header('Location: index.php?page=member.php');
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for you answer! I tested your code but when I login now, both user(admin and member) are "members".

Comment: Is `email` unique in the table? What is the output of the query? Replace `header` with echo and see which branch the code takes.

Comment: My email in my database is not unique. Should it be? The query takes the branch to "members" into the else

Comment: Well you seem to try to identify your users from their email address. If this is not unique, then there obviously is something wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Email is now unique. After login, both going still to ' index.php?page=member.php '